# Device is not ready, damaged HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Laptop HDD (IDE, 60GB) with Windows XP doesn't boot. I tried to boot from LiveUSB Ubuntu, and tried commands for detecting disks (sudo fdisk -l, fsblk -o), disk is not presented (Linux doesn't see it).

I tried to remove HDD from laptop and connect via reduction to my computer with Windows 7 and Disk Manager see it, but device is unknwon and need to be initialized. When I click on Initialize and choose: MBR initialization.

[Error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0aCcl.png):

> Device is not ready.

[image]

TestDisk and MiniTool Partition Wizard doesn't see this disk.